# Unable to make request with Alamofire upon receiving silent push while in background

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Our backend sends our app a silent push when certain events take place. Upon receiving the silent push, the app is supposed to make an API call to the server so that when the user opens the app later on, he sees updated content. The app receives the silent push notification but Alamofire doesn't make the request to our backend. The following is my implementation of the AppDelegate method which is invoked when a silent push is received (code has been redacted a bit to make it easier to read):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    self.alamoFireManager.request("someUrl/", method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON {
        response in

        //Parse data...
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
}
```

The self.alamoFireManager is set up as follows:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = timeout
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = timeout

self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

Here is where it gets strange. When I launch the app from Xcode and put it in the background and send a push from the server to the app, the app receives the push notification and makes the necessary request to the server. When I kill the app and launch the app normally on the device (not through Xcode), and trigger a push, the app never makes the request. I can't determine whether it's that the push doesn't arrive or whether it's that AF is not making the request but the push notification is configured correctly (has the content-available with a value of 1) and the corresponding delegate method is invoked in the debugger at least so I think it's that AF is not making the request. I also changed the URLSessionConfiguration to be a background session like so:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "someIdentifier")
```

This change had no visible effect on the behavior of the app. What am I doing wrong? Does Alamofire not support making requests (using request()) while the app is in the background? Do I have to use NSURLSession directly? This is my first time working with any silent push-triggered background requests. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Regards
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting a local notification in the didReceiveRemoteNotification method I noticed that the notification was only posted when the app was started from Xcode. When starting the app from the device directly the app never posted the local notification. This leads me to believe that my app is not actually being woken up by the push notification. This therefore has nothing to do with Alamofire at this time so I will close this question.

Comment: After analysing the APNS logs on my iOS device using the Mac's console app, I saw that the push notifications were arriving on the iOS device but that background app refresh had been disabled for the app. After checking the settings of the app in the iOS settings app, I saw that the background app refresh switch had been set to off. After re-enabling this I started receiving the notifications. I guess I should have checked there first but at least I learned about looking at the APNS logs through mac's Console app. You can even log to it from an app using os.log!

Comment: What alternative or solution did you found?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the appropriate background modes for your app target? You need to set them in order for the system to launch/wake up your app in the background in response to push notifications:

[image: background modes]

Generally you shouldn't rely on the debugger when testing background behaviour, as it prevents iOS from suspending the application. Nonetheless, it *will* be suspended when running it normally (without the debugger), and it will result in confusion like what you're experiencing.

> IMPORTANT As mentioned above, the debugger prevents your app from suspending.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14855

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes the background modes are enabled. However I tried to post a local notification when my app delegate's didReceiveRemoteNotification method gets called and I can see now that the notification is posted when started via the debugger and not posted when started outside of the debugger. So I seem to be having an issue with my app not being woken up from the background...

Comment: Be aware that _local_ notifications _can't_ wake up your application by design! Only remote notifications do. You should test your app with remote notifications, e.g. via the `apn` tool: https://github.com/nomad/houston